# How to create structure "Author -> Book -> Quote"?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need to create structure [taxonomy_term] Author -> [taxonomy_term] Book -> [node] Quote.
I already have the following structure: [taxonomy_term] "Author name and Book name" -> [node] "Quote". Now I want to split vocabulary "Author name and Book name" into 2 different vocabularies: "Author" and "Book" and link them to each other and to node type "Quote" to get the following hierarchy:

- Author [taxonomy_term]

  - Book [taxonomy_term]

    - Quote [node]
    - Quote [node]
  - Book [taxonomy_term]

    - Quote [node]
    - Quote [node]

I can create this hierarchy using Entity reference, but I don't know how to achieve the following.

On node (Quote) creation user should be able to:

- choose existing "Author" term and existing "Book" term that belongs to this Author (conditional select);
- choose existing "Author" term and create new "Book" term (and link this book to "Author" term);
- create new "Author" and "Book" terms (using taxonomy autocomplete widget) and link them to each other.

Is there any way to achieve this using existing Drupal modules?

Please note: I need to use 2 different vocabularies for authors and books. I know that it would be much easier to use 1 vocabulary and parent-child hierarchy of terms, but that is not suitable in my case.

Comment: what community modules have you already researched ?

Comment: [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) (base module for my goal), [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) (does not seem to be useful in my case), [Corresponding Entity References](https://drupal.org/project/cer) (this module not working and seems to be broken for now)

Comment: I'm starting to think that I will have to write custom module for my needs, and use hook_node_presave() to make references between terms programmaticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex business like this is hard "out of the box" with Drupal. Everyones custom logic like you've listed is different -- so community modules regularly dont let you define just deep nesting of logic.

I suspect you'll have to create some custom code to enforce relationships you want (form  validation logic).

Additionally, look at [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), [Entity Inline Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and perhaps the [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

You can use these modules to build the dependant drop down select lists, and a button to create the Book or Author for a quote as needed -- the prepopulate module could let you pass info from a book or author on creation, to the reference entity.

You may want to look at [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) or [Renderable Elements](https://drupal.org/project/rel) to tweak how the node form(s) are layed out.

As I said this isn't a solution but tools to help you build your own business-logic solution.